# Unconfirmed after 48 hours and counting still ... Someone please help me

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

https://blockchain.info/tx/ad9f5be7f893c8a2e6d977dce0367dcdaae20074c7eaa1f3ff288baf8f3a0059

I am new to this i have seen someone else accelerate anothers transaction can someone please help me with this i am new i didnt know about fees i left everything the way it was

Answer (score 0):

The transaction has been broadcast and nodes have viewed it, so as for the moment; you'll simply have to wait.

If there are a number of blocks found quickly; which happens... there will be less transactions transmittted due to the short time interval / blocks found, and the node that mined the block will accept and confirm funds sent with low TX fees.

But the reason it's stuck is your fee is too low.

If it's not confirmed after another day or two, it will likely be rejected back and ignored, thus returned to the original address.

The BTC isn't lost, it's just the block size is only so big, and there are so many transactions taking place, that if you do not "bid" a high enough fee you don't make the cut list.

The nodes are all programmed now to accept transactions based on "highest fee first, downward, until max block size is reached.

There is no work around.

Comment: So how much of a fee would i have to add next time for the same amount of btc